# How to get a Drift Report from Azure DevOps DACPAC deployment?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, dacpac, sqlpackage, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I would like to get a Drift-Report (and Deploy-Report and TSQL-script) during our DACPAC deployments.

We are running DACPAC deployment in Azure DevOps to on-prem SQL server, using the agent task "WinRM - SQL Server DB deployment". 
This task is utilizing [SQLPacakge.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017) and it's possible to pass "Additional Arguments" to the task.
But if I add `/Action:DriftReport` to the arguments, I get this runtime error:

> *** Duplicate 'Action' argument 'DriftReport'.

My assumtion is, that `/Action:Publish` is already provided by the winRM task. But is is possible to change it?

PS: I notice that the "Azure SQL Database Deployment" task in Azure DevOps does not have the same issue. There is a `Action` dropdown for selecting Publish, Drift Report, etc.

Comment: Wow, it's lonely on this internetz :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can be late, but I found a recommendation from Microsoft for use a powershell task given the action that you need, because the task only support publish action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=azure-devops

Comment: Even though links provide the actual source of the documentation, please consider adding quoted texts of what might be relevant, in case of future broken links.

Comment: I had to do something similar, there's an example in the answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180812/can-i-use-the-deployreport-option-when-deploying-a-dacpac-through-release-manage